# Magento Server copy to local server giving tmp error

Tags: magento-1.7

I copied all the files from live server to local xampp server. when I run the url, getting below tmp error. How to resolve the issue?

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\lib\Zend\Cache.php on line 153

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\lib\Zend\Cache.php(153): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Use of undefine...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 153, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\lib\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, true, true)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'File', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

After done the changes, now I am getting below error when login as admin:

```
Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected.  in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php on line 360

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'Header may not ...',   'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 360, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php(360): header('Location: http:...', true, 302)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Response\Http.php(78): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendHeaders()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Response\Http.php(115):  Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->sendHeaders()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Admin\Model\Session.php(135): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->sendHeadersAndExit()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Admin\Model\Observer.php(69): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('surestce', '12345678', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#12  C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
 #17 {main}
```

Comment: Did you delete all your cache files in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopmyga\var\cache

Comment: yes. I deleted all my cache files (\var\cache) and session files (\var\session)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the file path `[rootfolder]\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend.php` and line number **174**.

Go through the function `getTmpDir` and check you have sufficient permission for **tmp** folder and access to write files in **tmp**

Answer (score 0):

compile your website and clear cache and disable developer mode 
use cmd to do this 
php shell/compiler.php  --clear
php shell/compiler.php --compile
php shell/indexer.php   --reindex

reload your website and if OK run 
php shell/compiler.php  --disable